.Net Choosing Target OS Version and Supported OS Version
So I am developing an Windows application, based on .Net 8 and using WPF. I have configure the project and all but now I am facing the question, how to choose Target OS Version and Supported OS Version. I know this application will only be installed on Windows 10 or upwards.
Would it make sense to choose Target OS version and Supported OS Version to 10?

I am trying to find explanations on how they work but it's hard to come across decent documentation/explanations. The three link I have used to draw up my questions: one, two and three.
Here are my questions (and guesses on the answers).

If your end OS is known, does it make sense to choose a lower Target OS version? What are the advantages of choosing the highest possible version? I assume that you have access to more specific OS functions, but if you don't use them, does it still make sense to choose the highest possible?
Does it even make sense to choose a Target version that is less than the supported? What is the point of distinguishing between those too? Shouldn't your target always be the minimum you want to support? The supported OS version explanation seems to imply that its the target os version with extra code (less performant) to make it compatible to the supported version.
Is there an impact on performance? Does it change for instance if you use Windows 7 version vs Windows 10 version on Windows 10?

Yeah let's start with this questions first, then I could follow up with more details that I don't understand. Any additional documentation or answers are appreciated too!

This only matters to platforms that have been bitten by the agile bug, UWP and MAUI.  Not to WPF.

Targeting Windows 10 instead of Windows 7 will add a dependency on the Windows App SDK (letting you use WinUI 3), which increases your app's size by about 25 MB.

Choose the minimum supported Operating System version the framework is capable of (the oldest version of Windows). This widens compatibility.
There is no advantage to limiting the minimum supported version (to newest versions of windows), unless your application specifically needs a dependency that is only in the newer version of Windows.
Maybe it has a performance difference in allowing compatibility with older versions of Windows, but that might be negligible in your use case. You'll have to benchmark it and compare and consider if there is any value.
A client desktop application won't utilise much more by allowing it work with older machines. These kinds of considerations make more of a difference in a server environment receiving thousands of requests as that can significantly slow down the server. I don't imagine a desktop client application having the same issue unless it is badly written.
